# How likely is token collision with Python secrets library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, token

How likely is it for a collision to occur with tokens generated using Python's secrets library (https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html)?

There doesn't seem to be any mention of their uniqueness.

Comment: "**The secrets module provides access to the most secure source of randomness that your operating system provides.**".  Meaning if you generate say a 32 bit token, each if the 4294967296 (2^32) values should be equally frequent.  `secrets` isn't for generating unique identifiers, but gathering secure entropy (which can effectively be used for making unique identifiers, just make the token size sufficiently large).  Specs like UUID use other methods to "guarantee" uniqueness, like allocating bits for the time the ID was generated

Comment: Hmmm, I read that bit already, I was hoping for someone to say that uniqueness is guaranteed like in UUID. It makes me uncomfortable knowing that their is the possibility of a security token being generated that is the same as an existing one :/

Comment: Again about making the numbers of bits sufficiently large, you can use so many bits that you wouldn't expect a collision to ever occur within whatever enormous timescale makes you comfortable.  Even UUID can have collisions.  Interesting answer from this [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Has-there-ever-been-a-UUID-collision) "If every person on the planet generates a new UUID4 every second, we'd expect a collision to occur after about 10 years...".  Also here's an interesting article about Instagram's strategy for unique IDs https://instagram-engineering.com/sharding-ids-at-instagram-1cf5a71e5a5c

Comment: @HymnsForDisco Feel free to summarize your comments as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The purpose of the `secrets` module, is for sourcing *secret* data, i.e. information that cannot be predicted or reverse engineered

> The secrets module provides access to the most secure source of
>   randomness that your operating system provides.

Typically, the OS will use several entropy sources to generate bits. e.g. process id, thread id, mouse / keyboard input timings, CPU counters, system time, etc.

So long as the amount of entropy is sufficiently large for the amount of bits being generated (and again the OS uses many sources and accumulates entropy constantly), we should expect a uniform distribution of all values.  So if you generate a 32 bit key, you should expect to see each of the 4294967296 values with similar frequency.

To estimate how long before we expect a collision, we are essentially looking at the [Birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).  In general, if the values are uniformly distributed, and the number of values is `n`, we should expect a collision to occur after generating about `sqrt(n)` values (though in reality it's a bit more).

You can verify this with a quick benchmark program

```py
import secrets

def find_collision(b):
    tokens = set()
    while True:
        token = secrets.token_bytes(b)
        if token in tokens:
            return len(tokens)
        tokens.add(token)

b = 4
samples = 100
l = [find_collision(b) for i in range(samples)]
avg = sum(l)/len(l)

print(f'n = {2**(b*8)}, sqrt(n) = {2**(b*8/2)}')
print(f'on average, with a {b} byte token, a collision occurs after {avg} values')
```

```
n = 4294967296, sqrt(n) = 65536.0
on average, with a 4 byte token, a collision occurs after 75797.78 values
```

`secrets` makes no aims or claims about uniqueness, as the goal is to generate high entropy, *random* bytes that should be impossible to predict or reverse engineer.  To add constraints to the module to prevent duplicates would inherently make it more predictable.  In addition, `secrets` feeds you these bytes in a stream under the assumption that you take what you need, and use it how you like, so preventing duplicates doesn't make much sense as an upstream responsibility.  This is in contrast to something like a UUID, which has a fixed width and is intended to be used as a portable identifier and recognized datatype.

Comment: If one wanted uniqueness AND cryptographic security, could you use a Fernet-encrypted UUID4 string (with a central randomly-generated secret used for the encryption key)?

Comment: @BenDavis This should probably be it's own question on security stack exchange (unfortunately I don't know the answer).

Comment: To be sure to understand, if a generate a token using `token_urlsafe(32)` (base64), instead of `token_bytes(32)`, I get 64^32 possibilities instead of 2^32? In that case, this would be more powerful than uuid4 to avoid collisions right?

Comment: @DavidD. Each of the `secrets.token_*` functions takes an equivalent parameter, that is the number of random **bytes**. Meaning, `token_urlsafe(32)` and `token_bytes(32)` are equivalent from a randomness standpoint. What differs is the *encoding* only. See [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#secrets.token_urlsafe) and [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#how-many-bytes-should-tokens-use).

Comment: @DavidD. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)), the UUID4 has only 122 bits of random data. This means that a token with 16 or more bytes (`128 bits`) will have lesser probability of collisions.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco Ohh I understand better, thanks for the explanation!